# how to get a whitespace - whitespace recursively after all my track numbers in my music folder with the command line

Tags: command-line

How can I get a white-space dash white-space recursively after all my track numbers in my music folder with the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You should also indicate how your file names currently appear. If, for example, a folder containing a list of files looks like this:

```
$ ls -1v
1Music.mp3
2Music.mp3
3Music.mp3
4Music.mp3
5Music.mp3
6Music.mp3
7Music.mp3
8Music.mp3
9Music.mp3
10Music.mp3
```

We can use:

```
rename "s/(^[0-9]+)/\$1\ \-\ /" *.mp3
```

To get:

```
'1 - Music.mp3'
'2 - Music.mp3'
'3 - Music.mp3'
'4 - Music.mp3'
'5 - Music.mp3'
'6 - Music.mp3'
'7 - Music.mp3'
'8 - Music.mp3'
'9 - Music.mp3'
'10 - Music.mp3'
```

To be on the safe side, use the `-n` option to test your command first:

```
rename -n "s/(^[0-9]+)/\$1\ \-\ /" *.mp3
```

This command will show how the files will be renamed, without actually renaming them.

Comment: Can someone break the expression find . -regex '.*\.\s.*'
down for me so I can understand what the various characters mean to make adjustments?I would like to use rename to get from 01. Nobody's Diary.mp3 to 01 - Nobody's Diary.mp3 ?

Comment: @user179732 please edit that information into your question

Comment: How can I get rid of the . when I use "rename -n "s/(^[0-9]+)/\$1\ \-\ /" *.mp3" to get from "rename(11. Lie About Us.mp3, 11 - . Lie About Us.mp3)"

Answer (score 0):

You can search for such a filename pattern using a regular expression.

```
find . -regex '.*\s\-\s.*'
```

- Use the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command which searches recursively by default. The `.` as the first argument represents the path to search in, you can replace it with any arbitrary path if you don’t want to search in the current working directory.
- Whitespace is represented by `\s` in regular expressions.
- I’ll assume you mean [*hyphen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) (which can be found on the keyboard) by the term [*dash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). However, the hyphen has special meaning in regular expressions and must be [escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) using `\-`. If you want to include other dash types, you should cover them using a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in your regex, e.g. `[\-–—]`.
- Starting and ending the regex with `.*` allows any characters (including none) before and after the pattern we focus on.